# Mail para mesma página em php

Tags: php, phpmailer

Gente estou com uma certa dúvida e queria maiores atualizações
Eu tenho o seguinte código

```
// VALIDAÇÃO DE DADOS

$chCC_Nome=$_POST['chCC_Nome'];
$chCC_Assunto=$_POST['chCC_Assunto'];
$chCC_Email=$_POST['chCC_Email'];
$chCC_Mensagem=$_POST['chCC_Mensagem'];

// ENVIAR DADOS

mail("Contato <contato@meudominio.com","$chCC_Assunto","
NOME DE IDENTIFICAÇÃO.: $chCC_Nome
EMAIL ELETRÔNICO.: $chCC_Email
MENSAGEM: $chCC_Mensagem","FROM: $chCC_Nome < $chCC_Email >");
<form name="form" accept-charset="ISO-8859-1" method="post" action="?st=contato" id="mainform">
<input name="chCC_Assunto" type="hidden" id="chPP_Assunto" value="PG CTS" />
<input name="chCC_Nome" type="text" placeholder="Nome Completo" required />
<input name="chCC_Email" type="text" placeholder="Endereço Eletrônico" required  />
<input name="chCC_Email" type="text" placeholder="Mensagem" required  />
<input class="submit" type="submit" value="Enviar" />
```

Como faço pra enviar para mesma página sem redirecionar para outra e informar uma mensagem dizendo que foi enviado com sucesso!﻿﻿

Agradeço desde já.!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segundo a própria documentação do [mail()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mail.php), ele irá retornar `TRUE` se o email for aceito com sucesso para ser enviado, caso contrario, irá retornar `FALSE`. Ou seja, mesmo que o email seja aceito para ser enviado, não quer dizer que ele necessariamente chegou ao destino.
Então oque você pode estar fazendo é colocar um `if` para verificar se ele irá retornar `TRUE` ou `FALSE` e fazer ele exibir uma mensagem em seguida usando `echo()`

Código:

```
// VALIDAÇÃO DE DADOS

$chCC_Nome=$_POST['chCC_Nome'];
$chCC_Assunto=$_POST['chCC_Assunto'];
$chCC_Email=$_POST['chCC_Email'];
$chCC_Mensagem=$_POST['chCC_Mensagem'];

// ENVIAR DADOS

if(@mail("Contato <contato@meudominio.com","$chCC_Assunto","
   NOME DE IDENTIFICAÇÃO.: $chCC_Nome
   EMAIL ELETRÔNICO.: $chCC_Email
   MENSAGEM: $chCC_Mensagem","FROM: $chCC_Nome < $chCC_Email >")){
   echo "Email enviado com sucesso";
}else{
   echo "Email não enviado";
}

<form name="form" accept-charset="ISO-8859-1" method="post" action="?st=contato" id="mainform">
<input name="chCC_Assunto" type="hidden" id="chPP_Assunto" value="PG CTS" />
<input name="chCC_Nome" type="text" placeholder="Nome Completo" required />
<input name="chCC_Email" type="text" placeholder="Endereço Eletrônico" required  />
<input name="chCC_Email" type="text" placeholder="Mensagem" required  />
<input class="submit" type="submit" value="Enviar" />
```

Comment: Obrigado Tales por consegui tirar a minha dúvida, eu estava com essa super dúvida a muito tempo, espero que ajude a outras pessoas também este post.